# styled-components styles are not applied when using a React custom element

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, custom-element

UPDATE: I never got styled-components to apply in a React custom element. What I ended up doing is upgrading to mui v5(including the use of emotion) and there I was able to use styled from @mui/material/styles and makeStyles from @mui/styles just fine.
See here [How to create insertion point to mount styles in shadow dom for MUI material v5 in React custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813276/how-to-create-insertion-point-to-mount-styles-in-shadow-dom-for-mui-material-v5)

ORIGINAL:
I had this React application in which the styled-components were applied just fine and everything worked great. I have now converted this app to a custom element and now the styled-components are not being applied. Any help is appreciated.

Item.styles.tsx <---holds the styled components

```
export const ItemBody = styled.section`
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
   padding: 0 1.25rem;
`;
export const ItemDetailContainer = styled.div`
   margin: 0.25rem;
   min-height: 5rem;
`;
// and so on
```

MyItem.tsx

```
import {
    ItemBody,
    ItemDetailContainer,
    ItemButton,
} from './../styles/Item.styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    descriptionWrapper: {
       fontSize: '1.5rem',
       fontWeight: 900,
    }
    // and so on. NOTE: These styles ARE still getting applied but not the imported ones
}));

type Props = {
    itemId: string;
    itemName: string;
    itemDescription?: string[];
};

const MyItem: React.FC<Props> = ({
    itemId,
    itemName,
    itemDescription,
}) => {
   const classes = useStyles();

   return (
      <div key={tileIndex}>
         <ItemBody>                                          //style NOT applied
            <ItemDetailContainer>                            //style NOT applied
               <span className={classes.descriptionWrapper}> //style IS applied
                  {itemDescription}
               </span>
            </ItemDetailContainer>
        </ItemBody>
      //and so on
   );
};

export default MyItem;
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import MyItem from './components/MyItem';
import './App.styles.css';
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div className='App'>
              <MyItem />
           </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {
    StylesProvider,
    jssPreset,
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { create } from 'jss';

class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        const mountPoint = document.createElement('custom-jss-insertion-point');
        const reactRoot = shadowRoot.appendChild(mountPoint);
        const jss = create({
            ...jssPreset(),
            insertionPoint: reactRoot,
        });

        render(
            <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
                <App />
            </StylesProvider>,
            mountPoint
        );
    }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyWebComponent);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>React Custom Element</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <my-element id="elem"></my-element>
      <div id="root"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        app: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.tsx'),
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/index.html',
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'react-web-component-style-loader' },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                ],
            },
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
        fallback: { constants: require.resolve('constants-browserify') },
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
            favicon: './public/favicon.ico',
            filename: 'index.html',
            manifest: './public/manifest.json',
            logo192: './logo192.png',
        }),
        new Dotenv(),
    ],
};
```

Comment: are the styled components being rendered in the DOM & just missing the CSS properties?

Comment: Thanks for asking cts as it had not occurred to me to check. I still have the old React application(before it was turned into a custom element) and after comparing them, I can clearly see that yes, the styled component is showing up in the DOM when I run it but is is only the CSS properties missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment, and im no tsx coder, but could it be that the import in MyItem.tsx is missing "from"?

```
import {
    ItemBody
    ItemDetailContainer
    ItemButton
}'./../styles/Item.styles';
```

should be

```
import {
    ItemBody,
    ItemDetailContainer,
    ItemButton
} from './../styles/Item.styles';
```

Don't forget to comma separate the imports!

Comment: Thanks but that was just a copy paste issue on my side. 'from' is actually there in the code.  And there are commas in there. I will udpate this in the post. Thanks for pointing it out.