# How to create insertion point to mount styles in shadow dom for MUI material v5 in React custom element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, custom-element, react-typescript

Using @material-ui/core V4(4.12.3 to be exact) I HAD a custom element created successfully using webpack and babel. I used to be styling it using the @material-ui/core makeStyles. Now I am upgrading to @mui/material v5 and want to use the built-in components from @mui/material but they do not display styled within the custom element.
Please note that I need this to be a custom element as it will be integrated within another hosting app.

index.tsx BEFORE in v4

```
import AppComponent from './App';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { create } from 'jss';

class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        const mountPoint = document.createElement('custom-jss-insertion-point');
        const reactRoot = shadowRoot.appendChild(mountPoint);
        const jss = create({
            ...jssPreset(),
            insertionPoint: reactRoot,
        });

        render(
            <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
                <AppComponent />
            </StylesProvider>,
            mountPoint
        );
    }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyWebComponent);
```

Upgrading to @mui/material v5(v5.0.4 to be exact), first I tried with StyledEngineProvider in order to mount styles. Then I tried with @mui/styles jssPreset. Either way doesn't work. What I mean by doesn't work is that DataContainer which is referenced by AppComponent has @mui/material components and they are all loading without any styles (such as Grid, Button, InputLabel, Select, any many more).

First try with StyledEngineProvider

```
import AppComponent from './App';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme, StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
    

const theme = createTheme();

class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        // can't use jss in mui v5
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        const mountPoint = document.createElement('custom-insertion-point');
        const reactRoot = shadowRoot.appendChild(mountPoint);

        render(
            <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <AppComponent />
            </ThemeProvider>
            </StyledEngineProvider>,
            mountPoint //I have also used reactRoot here instead and got same result
        );
    }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyWebComponent);
```

Second try with @mui/styles jssPreset

```
import AppComponent from './App';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@mui/styles';
import { create } from 'jss';

class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        const mountPoint = document.getElementById('jss-insertion-point');
        const reactRoot = shadowRoot.appendChild(mountPoint);
        const jss = create({
            ...jssPreset(),
            insertionPoint: reactRoot,
        });

        render(
            <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
                <AppComponent />
            </StylesProvider>,
            mountPoint
        );       
    }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyWebComponent);
```

AppComponent

```
import React from 'react';
import { Suspense } from 'react';
import DataContainer from './components/DataContainer';

class AppComponent extends React.Component<any> {
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Suspense fallback='Loading...'>
                <div className='AppComponent'>
                    <DataContainer />
                </div>
            </Suspense>
        );
    }
}
export default AppComponent;
```

DataContainer

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));

export default function FullWidthGrid() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={6} md={8}>
          <Button variant="contained">xs=6 md=8</Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} md={4}>
          <Item>xs=6 md=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} md={4}>
          <Item>xs=6 md=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} md={8}>
          <Item>xs=6 md=8</Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <div>
        <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 180 }}>
          <Select autoWidth>
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={21}>Twenty one</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={22}>Twenty one and a half</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
        <title>React Custom Element</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <my-element id="elem"> </my-element>
        </body>
</html>
```

This is what I see:

[image]

This is what I'm supposed to see as shown in this stackblitz. (Note that I was unable to create a stackblitz with a custom element unfortunately)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d8xtdu?file=index.js

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

You need to create `style` tag. This will be entry point to emotion (material ui 5 styling solution) to insert scoped shadow DOM styles.

Next step is to configure jss and emotion cache

```
const jss = create({
    ...jssPreset(),
    insertionPoint: reactRoot,
});

const cache = createCache({
    key: 'css',
    prepend: true,
    container: emotionRoot,
 });
```

Last thing to do is to wrap our tree in providers

```
render(
   <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
      <CacheProvider value={cache}>
         <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Demo />
         </ThemeProvider>
      </CacheProvider>
   </StylesProvider>,
   mountPoint
);
```

Full example:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Demo from './demo';
    import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
    import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@mui/styles';
    import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
    import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
    import { create } from 'jss';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    
    const theme = createTheme();
    
    class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        const emotionRoot = document.createElement('style');
        const mountPoint = document.createElement('div');
        shadowRoot.appendChild(emotionRoot);
        const reactRoot = shadowRoot.appendChild(mountPoint);
    
        const jss = create({
          ...jssPreset(),
          insertionPoint: reactRoot,
        });
    
        const cache = createCache({
          key: 'css',
          prepend: true,
          container: emotionRoot,
        });
    
        render(
          <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
            <CacheProvider value={cache}>
              <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Demo />
              </ThemeProvider>
            </CacheProvider>
          </StylesProvider>,
          mountPoint
        );
      }
    }
    if (!customElements.get('my-element')) {
      customElements.define('my-element', MyWebComponent);
    }
```

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman please review ;)

Comment: One issue I see now is that the drop down items inside the Select drop down are not showing up properly (styling wise) and the click events are also not working correctly for the Select. I created question for this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69828392/mui-select-drop-down-selections-not-styled-when-using-entry-point-to-insert-scop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69829151/12860195